# Different colored columns in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, microsoft-excel-2013

I have data such as this:

```
1 | 2 | Y
2 | 4 | N
3 | 3 | N
4 | 2 | Y
...
```

I need a bar graph that will display column 1 as the x-axis labels with column 2 as the y values. The color of each bar will be determined by column 3: red if `N` and blue if `Y`. Is there a way to do this? Also, I have 2013 Excel with Office 365.

Comment: You need helper columns.  If the value is 'N' in column 3 then place the value in column 4 else place #N/A in column 4.  Do the same for 'Y' in column 5.  Create the line graph for column 1/4 and column 1/5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @wbeard52 stated you'll need helper columns

At the end your data will look like this:

```
    A    B    C      D
1   2    Y    2      #N/A
2   4    N    #N/A   4
3   3    N    #N/A   3
4   2    Y    2      #N/A
```

To achieve that, you'll need the following formulas

In C1 (and copied down)

```
=IF(B2="Y",A2,NA())
```

In D1 (and copied down)

```
=IF(B2="N",A2,NA())
```

Then you'll create a stacked column chart with column C as the Y values, and column D as the N values. And can then color them as you wish.